# Regex replace everything except match

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I would like to keep just words that start with '@' and continue with letters or dots. Basically I have done opposite that I can match such a words but don't know how to match everything besides this match. So basically just keep those that starts with '@'. So far I have this patter:

```
(@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\b)
```

I tried to use '?!' but it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: so `if` you have a match, `replace`, otherwise *don't do anything*... let regex as is and do the "negation" in python...

Comment: How? I got str.replace from pandas , where I should but negation? Thanks

Comment: Don't even match & negate & replace, instead match & join (the set of `@words`)

Comment: Example : https://ideone.com/WqvV5H (note that I used `\w` for simplicity but it's not equivalent to your class. The trailing `\b` however can be safely removed, as well as the enclosing capturing group)

Comment: Is there any way how to make this negation in regex or using pandas replace? I know about function extractall but the result is multiindex frame and str.extract extracts just first occurance

Comment: That pattern matches anything containing an `@`, e.g. for `"a @b c@d"` it would  match `@b` *and* `@d`. Is that what you want?

Comment: @mata well, you are right, this is not what I want. If I change it to ^(@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\b) then it catches just first line. Any idea how to catch it anywhere?

Comment: what about `(?:^|\s)(?:(?!@).)*` ? are the words define by something between whitespace

Comment: Something like `re.findall(r"(?:\A|\s)(@[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\b)", "@a @b @c@d e@f")` seems to do it, but also catches `@c` since `@` is a word boundary

Comment: thanks a lot! Nahuel's solutions works best to me!

Comment: @JohnSnow, It's not exactly the contrary, it will leave `@other_characters` for example it is the contrary of `@\S+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments, the following regex is ok

```
(?:^|\s)[^@]*
```

exact contrary would be

```
(?:^|[^@A-Za-z0-9.]|@(?![A-Za-z0-9.]+\b))[^@]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this Regex Expression:

> (@+[a-zA-Z0-9.]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)

I tested it on-line and it does what you are looking for ( match every words that starts with @ and it can continue with dots, es: @hello.sir match | @hello.sir.do match and so on.. )